# Exception in reading Xlxs filenull

Tags: java, excel, excel-reader

This is my script code. i am trying to extract data from excel sheet but there is an error saying exception in reading xlxs filenull

```
public class TC003_VerifyLoginWithDifferentRecords extends testbase {

    public static final Logger log = 
    Logger.getLogger(TC003_VerifyLoginWithDifferentRecords.class.getName());
    HomePage homepage;

    @DataProvider(name = "logindata")
    public String[][] getTestData()
    {
        String[][]testRecords = getData("TestData.xlsx","LoginTestData");   
        return testRecords;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp()
    {
        init();
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "logindata")
    public void TestLogin(String emailAddress, String Password)
    {
        log.info("================Starting VerifyLogin with Different 
        Records===================");
        homepage = new HomePage(driver);
        homepage.loginApplication(emailAddress,Password);
        log.info("================Ending VerifyLogin with Different Records===================");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void endTest()
    {
        // driver.close();
    }
```

This is mt testbase class where i have provided path of the excel sheet

```
public String[][] getData(String workbookname, String sheetname)
{

    String path = "H:/JAVA TESTING CODES/UIAutomation/src/main/java/com/test/automation/UIAutomation/data"+workbookname;
    excel = new ExcelReader(path);
    String[][] data = excel.getDataFromSheet(workbookname, sheetname);
    return data;
}
```

Comment: `"H:/JAVA TESTING CODES/UIAutomation/src/main/java/com/test/automation/UIAutomation/data" +workbookname;` Assuming `data` is a folder, don't you need a trailing `/`?

Comment: I tried with trailing / but there is a same error

Comment: Please provide much more detail. Which line gives the error, for instance. What are the values passed to the function that gives the error etc? This seems something that is quite easily debuggable by yourself - I don't think there's anything tricky that means [SO] questions are the best  way of solving it.

Comment: String[][] data = excel.getDataFromSheet(workbookname, sheetname); from test base

Comment: String[][]testRecords = getData("TestData.xlsx","LoginTestData");  from my script file

Comment: ] com.test.automation.UIAutomation.Homepage.TC003_VerifyLoginWithDifferentRecords.getTestData() must return either Object[][] or Iterator<Object>[], not class [[Ljava.lang.String; here is a brief error that came after debugging

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue but then In my excel I checked the below 3 points.

1) If you are not using Microsoft product excel then please use HSSF classes everywhere in your Excel_reader class.
2) You have to convert all your data to to String format in excel by using excel options like Change to TEXT to Columns.
3) Your sheet should exactly the same name which you are passing as an argument in your function like LoginTestData in your case, also Workbook name should be having TestData.xlsx the same name as provided in the function

check with the above 3 points and let me know if issue still persists, because i have done the same coding like you have done but with above 3 points taken into consideration and it worked